# What is "cooked mode" wifi monitoring?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, monitoring, tcpdump, iw

The following is an excerpt from `iw`'s `help` page:

```
dev <devname> set monitor *
        Set monitor flags. Valid flags are:
        none:     no special flags
        fcsfail:  show frames with FCS errors
        control:  show control frames
        otherbss: show frames from other BSSes
        cook:     use cooked mode
        active:   use active mode (ACK incoming unicast packets)
        mumimo-groupid : use MUMIMO according to a group id
        mumimo-follow-mac : use MUMIMO according to a MAC address
```

What is "cooked mode" wifi monitoring?

Comment: In general, Cooked mode means preprocessing of data before giving it to some program or system. So, iw must be activating some setting which gonna process first . Thoughe no idea, what exactly iw gonna processes here in this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a detailed information about these flags and I came across this information in [Aircrack-ng blog](https://aircrack-ng.blogspot.com/2017/02/monitor-mode-flags.html)

cook: Refer to a mode for HostAPd where authentication frames that mac80211 didn't actually look at. It is only for ancient versions of HostAPd.